More about the irrational sequence $u_{n+1}=\left| u_{n}-u_{n-1}\right|$
The convergence question of a sequence defined as $$u_{n+1}=\left| u_{n}-u_{n-1}\right|,$$ with $u_{0}$​ and $u_{1}$​ strictly positive, and such that $\dfrac{u_{1}}{u_{0}}\notin \mathbb{Q}$ - have been answered and explained by Carl Schildkraut there : An irrational sequence $ u_{n+1}=\left| u_{n}-u_{n-1}\right| $ .
However, I came across what appears to be a different solution to the same problem in a French practice paper. This paper outlines the solution strategy to the problem in 6 steps, which must be expanded into a full proof. I have trouble understanding the logic of this non-obvious strategy, starting with steps (5) and (6).
Here it is (fully quoted ):
(1)  Prove by induction that $\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_{n}}\notin \mathbb{Q}$ and $u_{n}\neq 0$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}.$
(2)  Let $v_{n}=\max \left\{ u_{n},u_{n+1}\right\}$.
By considering the cases
(a)      $u_{n}\leqslant u_{n+1}$   and
(b)      $0 <u_{n+1} <u_{n}$​,
show that $\left( v_{n}\right)$ is non-increasing and convergent.
Let $j$ be a fixed index.
(3)  Setting $k=\lfloor \dfrac{u_{j+1}}{u_{j}}\rfloor$ (then $u_{j+1}=ku_{j}+r$ and $0 <r <u_{j}$​), show that:
---if $k=0\Rightarrow v_{j}=u_{j}$;
---if $k=1\Rightarrow v_{j+2}\leqslant u_{j}$;
---in other cases and generally $( \exists n\geqslant j) :v_{n}\leqslant u_{j}$.
(4) Deduce from the previous step that $( \forall p\geqslant n) :u_{p}\leqslant u_{j}$.
(5) Deduce from the above that $ \left( u_{n}\right) \rightarrow \inf \left\{ u_{n}\right\}$.
(6) Hence show that $\left( u_{n}\right) \rightarrow 0$.
While steps (1)−(4) are technically not difficult to complete, I admit that I cannot discern the French author’s overall motivation for the chosen strategy…
Up until step (4) (inclusive), it is shown that each arbitrary term $ u_{j}$​ is an upper bound—from some point onward—of all subsequent terms in this sequence. But, as one can easily observe, $\left( u_{n}\right)$ is not monotonic: it jumps and falls… Thus, to “deduce” in points (5) and (6) the convergence of $\left( u_{n}\right)$ independently of the method presented by C. Schildkraut, it would likely be necessary to show that from some very large index onward,$\left( u_{n}\right)$ is a Cauchy sequence, or equivalently, that $\left| u_{n}-u_{n-1}\right| \rightarrow 0$. But this last condition implies, according to the definition of the sequence, $\left( u_{n}\right)$, that $\left( u_{n+1}\right) \rightarrow 0$... So we end up going in vicious circle...
Does the “French” strategy make any sense, then? Are steps (5) and (6) achievable logically from (4) and independently of the approach presented by C. Schildkraut?
Thank you in advance for any comments and suggestions.

Please, start with your actual question, not a couple of paragraphs of your history leading to the question. You can add the history after, but you want readers to be quickly able to tell if they can help you. Help people help you.

Mr. Andrews, I'm very sorry that I wasn't clear enough for you. In my question, I am asking to evaluate a given strategy for solving a problem, a strategy that seemed incoherent to me... So I had to quote this strategy...

You don't tell us the paper's problem until after a very long paragraph describing the strategy to the answer. Better to start: "I am  having trouble understanding a proof in a paper I'm reading showing ..." Then state the resullt the paper is trying to prove, and then thestrategy that has you confused. Skip the "similar" question completely.

Now is better ?

Assuming we reached step (4) in the french strategy, we know that
\begin{equation}
\forall j\in{\mathbb N}, \exists n\in{\mathbb N}, \forall p\ge n, u_p\le u_j
\end{equation}
In this inequality, we can take the limsup  when $p\to\infty$ to get
\begin{equation}
\forall j\in{\mathbb N}, \limsup_{p\to\infty}\ \{u_p\}\le u_j
\end{equation}
The left hand side does not depend on $j$, we can take the liminf when $j\to\infty$ to get
\begin{equation}
\limsup_{p\to\infty}\ \{u_p\}\le \liminf_{j\to\infty}\ \{u_j\}
\end{equation}
As $u_n$ is bounded, it follows that $u_n$ converges to a limit $\ell$.
We may pass to the limit in the relation $u_{n+1} = |u_n - u_{n-1}|$ to obtain
\begin{equation}
\ell = |\ell - \ell| = 0
\end{equation}
hence $u_n\to 0$ when $n\to\infty$.

How did you get $\limsup \left{ u_{n}\right} \leqslant \liminf \left{ u_{n}\right}$ ?

OK, thank you very much  !!!
